# How to delay the Execution of a Javascript Function After a Live Keyup event is called?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript

Hey programmers, I have removed everything from my function below to just target exactly what I need help with...

After the keyup event is called, the reloadContent function will make an ajax call to gather new data from a database.

Only problem is, my servers are overloading because there is no delay from the keyup events, after every keyup the function is called.

I need a way to delay, say 1 second, before the reloadContent function is called. This way it will not run 4 times (when the user types in j o h n) but only 1 time after the user types (john), assuming they can type more than 1 character/sec.

```
$('#searchinput').live('keyup',function() {

        reloadContent(); //execute load function

});
```

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a timeout in your `keyup` handler and use jQuery's [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) facility to associate its id with the element. That way, if the `keyup` event is triggered again before the delay runs out, you can clear the existing timeout and schedule a new one:

```
$("#searchinput").live("keyup", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var timerId = $this.data("timerId");
    if (timerId) {
        window.clearTimeout(timerId);
    }
    $this.data("timerId", window.setTimeout(reloadContent, 1000));
});
```

Comment: Got ya. That makes sense, I didn't even think about that. I will accept when it allows me to do so. Thank you I will use this often

Comment: works like a charm. Im sure this will help my server out, ill test tomorrow at peak hrs.

Comment: @Tom, IMHO `data()` is one of jQuery's best assets, as they eliminate the need for globals in most cases.

Comment: Absolutely. I was composing a reply using a global, then I saw your answer and was enlightened :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#searchinput').live('keyup',function() {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        reloadContent(); //execute load function
    },1000);
});
```

This will make a delay, but I think you need not only delay to make what you want.

Comment: Indeed, this will delay the AJAX calls but still run them in bursts.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, your example fixes this problem =)