# settimeout & cleartimeout to start time with a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, delay, jquery-events

I'm pretty new with Javascript and jQuery and can't quite figure out `settimeout`.

What I'm trying to do it start a timer with a click. It will slide a page to where there is an input to enter an email. If, in 20 seconds, there is nothing typed, I want it to do something. But if they do enter something, I'd like the 20 second timer reset to 20 seconds `onkeyup`. And finally, if the form is submitted, I want the timeout cancelled.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('#pane').scrollTo( '1000px', 500);
  setTimeout(goback, 20000);
  function goback() {
  $('#pane').scrollTo ('0px', 500);
  $('#input').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(goback);
    setTimeout(goback, 20000);
};
$('#submitemail').click(function(){
  //form submit stuff
  clearTimeout(goback);
});
```

Could you please point me in the right direction?

```
var timer;
$('#button').click(function(){
     $('#pane').scrollTo( '768px', 0 );
     $('#emailinput').delay(1000).focus();
     $('#slide2fadeout').css("display", "block").fadeOut();
     timer = setTimeout(goback, 20000);              //in 20 seconds start goback function
     function goback(){
         $('#like').scrollTo( '0px', 0 );            //scroll back to top
         $('#emailinput').val('');                   //clear any partial entry
     };
     $('#emailinput').keyup(function(){
         clearTimeout(timer);
         timer = setTimeout(goback, 20000);
     };
});
```

Here's my actual code... can't seem to get it working right. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166213/how-to-delay-the-execution-of-a-javascript-function-after-a-live-keyup-event-is-c/6166245)

Comment: @tom shaw, I can't figure out your link... thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delay the Execution of a Javascript Function After a Live Keyup event is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166213/how-to-delay-the-execution-of-a-javascript-function-after-a-live-keyup-event-is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the *return value* of `setTimeout` somewhere in order to cancel it later:

```
var timer;
$('#button').click(function () {
    ...
    timer = setTimeout(goback, 20000);
    ...
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Comment: @deceze, Thanks - so when .keyup, I need to do `timer = setTimeout(goback, 20000);` also?

Comment: Yes, on keyup, you should clear the timer, then "reset" it the same way.

Comment: @deceze, I've put my actual code up there... if you have a sec would you take a look and let me know what's wrong. Thanks

Comment: Well, *what is* wrong? What doesn't it do that it's supposed to?

Comment: when I click #button nothing happens.

Comment: I apologize for so many questions - im pretty new at this. never used settimeout

Comment: Check your browser's Javascript console, for starters. Anything there?